# Parasing a CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I found this function at [PSDecode](https://github.com/PrateekKumarSingh/PSDecode):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Short description
.DESCRIPTION
Long description
.PARAMETER ExitCode
Parameter description
.PARAMETER LocalJSONFilePath
Parameter description
.PARAMETER GithubJSONUrl
Parameter description
.EXAMPLE
An example
.NOTES
General notes
#>
Function Get-ErrorDetail
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [alias("err")]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] 
        [int32] $ErrorCode
    )

    Begin
    {
        Try
        {
            $Data = Import-csv "$(Location of the CSV file)"
        }
        Catch
        {
            "Something went wrong! please try running the script again."
        }
    }

    Process
    {
        Foreach ($Item in $ErrorCode)
        {
            If ($Item)
            {
                $Data | Where-Object {$_.exitCode -eq $ErrorCode}
            }
            else
            {
                $Data
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    End
    {}

}
```

The Original Function from the Github repo is

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Short description
.DESCRIPTION
Long description
.PARAMETER ExitCode
Parameter description
.PARAMETER LocalJSONFilePath
Parameter description
.PARAMETER GithubJSONUrl
Parameter description
.EXAMPLE
An example
.NOTES
General notes
#>
Function Get-ErrorDetail
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [alias("err")]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] 
        [int32] $ErrorCode
    )

    Begin
    {
        Try
        {
            $Data = Import-csv "$(Split-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot))\Data\ErrorCode.csv"
        }
        Catch
        {
            "Something went wrong! please try running the script again."
        }
    }

    Process
    {
        Foreach ($Item in $ErrorCode)
        {
            If ($Item)
            {
                $Data | Where-Object {$_.exitCode -eq $ErrorCode}
            }
            else
            {
                $Data
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    End
    {}

}
```

Per the Github Repo, I copied from if I do this

Expected:
(Start-Process Hostname.exe -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode | Get-ErrorDetail

| ErrorString | ExitCode | HexValue | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ERROR_SUCCESS | 0 | 0x0 | The operation completed successfully. |

Actual:
(Start-Process Hostname.exe -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode | Get-ErrorDetail

| ErrorString               | ExitCode | Hex Value | Description                                |   |
|---------------------------|----------|-----------|--------------------------------------------|---|
| ERROR_SUCCESS             | 0        | 0x0       | The operation completed successfully.      |   |
| ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION    | 1        | 0x1       | Incorrect function.                        |   |
| ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND      | 2        | 0x2       | The system cannot find the file specified. |   |
| ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND      | 3        | 0x3       | The system cannot find the path specified. |   |
| ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES | 4        | 0x4       | The system cannot open the file.           |   |
However, I get a list of the contents in the csv [found here](https://github.com/PrateekKumarSingh/PSDecode/blob/master/Data/ErrorCode.csv) file

I know I'm reinventing the wheel but when I tried to install the PSDecode module it didn't work correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, I will be posting this on Reddit at the [r/Poweshell](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/) subreddit as well.

Edit: Update Function

```
Thank you so far for all your help everyone. Here is what I have so far:

cmdletbinding()]
    [alias("err")]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] 
        [int32] $ErrorCode
    )
    

    Begin
    {
        Try
        {
            $filePath = "location of csv file"
            $Data = Import-Csv -Path $filePath -Header ErrorString,ExitCode,Hex_Value,Description
            $HashTable=@{}
            foreach($r in $Data)
            {
            if ($r.ErrorString -notlike '#*')
            {$HashTable[$r.ExitCode]=$r.Description}
            }
        }
        Catch
        {
            "Something went wrong! please try running the script again."
        }
    }

    Process 
    {
        Foreach ($Item in $ErrorCode)
        {
            If ($Item)
            {
                $Data | Where-Object {$_.exitCode -eq $ErrorNumber}
            }
            else
            {
                $Data
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    End
    {}

}
```

Edit 3
Per input from the comments

```
Function Get-ErrorDetail{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Short description
.DESCRIPTION
Long description
.PARAMETER ExitCode
Parameter description
.PARAMETER LocalJSONFilePath
Parameter description
.PARAMETER GithubJSONUrl
Parameter description
.EXAMPLE
An example
.NOTES
General notes
#>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] 
        [int32[]]$ErrorCode,

        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [string]$DataFile = "C:********\ErrorCode.csv"  # defaults to the current path the script is in
    )

    Begin 
    {
        Try
        {
        # convert the csv file into a Hashtable where the keys are the numeric codes and the values are the records themselves
        $errorHash = @{}
        Foreach ($code in (Import-Csv -Path $DataFile)) { 
            $errorHash[$code.ExitCode] = $code 
        } 
        }
        Catch
        {
            "Something went wrong! please try running the script again."
        }        
    }
    Process {
        Foreach ($code in $ErrorCode) 
       { $errorHash["$code"] }
    }
    End
    {}
}
```

However, I'm getting this error: Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.

Comment: [1] please add a sample of your CSV & the expected output to your Question.///// [2] your function lists 3 parameters, but only shows one. where are the rest? ///// [3] a hashtable for looking up the error code to friendly name seems more sensible.

Comment: Where is the function definition itself in the partial code you have copied? `Function Get-ErrorDetail {` including the closing bracket `}`

Comment: @Theo that is the function let me update it

Comment: Hmmm.. rather poorly written function I think. Since it only accepts one single `int32` value in parameter `$ErrorCode` there is no reason for a `foreach` loop. It also tests with `if($item)` meaning that if $item is 0, the if fails and the function returns all of the csv it read in.

Comment: Oh, how can I fix that?

Comment: On mobile now, so I'll try to post an answer tomorrow unless someone else does that in the meantime. I'd say @Lee_Dailey gave you the best hint already with the Hashtable approach

Comment: @Theo so import the csv into a hash table and pipe against the hashtable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230386/discussion-between-dre-and-theo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, I think the function is quite poorly written. It also uses a parameter help comment that for the most part does not apply..

Because it uses a `Where-Object` clause to search for a given code in a large set of objects, you could do better converting the imported data into a lookup Hashtable.

Sure, loading and converting takes time, but looking up a value in a hash is extremely fast.

Something like this would already be an improvement I think:

```
function Get-ErrorDetail {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] 
        [int32[]]$ErrorCode,

        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [string]$DataFile = "$PSScriptRoot\ErrorCode.csv"  # defaults to the current path the script is in
    )

    Begin {
        # convert the csv file into a Hashtable where the keys are the numeric codes and the values are the records themselves
        $errorHash = @{}
        foreach ($code in (Import-Csv -Path $DataFile)) { 
            $errorHash[$code.ExitCode] = $code 
        }
    }

    Process {
        foreach ($code in $ErrorCode) { $errorHash["$code"] }
    }
}
```

Now you can feed it more codes at once while the datafile is imported and converted only once like:

```
0, 5, 17 | Get-ErrorDetail
```

Output:

```
ErrorString           ExitCode Hex Value Description                                               
-----------           -------- --------- -----------                                               
ERROR_SUCCESS         0        0x0       The operation completed successfully.                     
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED   5        0x5       Access is denied.                                         
ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE 17       0x11      The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive.
```

I also added a second parameter `DataFile` with which you can specify a different path to the ErrorCode.csv if this is somewhere else than the path the script itself is in.

Comment: Thank you, I tried converting the CSV to a hashtable but I couldn't find a way to do it but I didn't see any way to covert a four-column  CSV

Comment: @Dre Well, now you know how easy that can be ;) BTW If you feel my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the large checkmark icon ✔️ to the left. This helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.